# phonegap device info shows ripple emulator but not on actual device

Tags: cordova

hi i am building a gps tracker web application with the aid of phonegap to be able to use my smartphone to send gps information trough web service.

but before running the function to get the actual location trough the navigator plugin i wish to first get the device information.

currently i am testing the application trough ripple where it runs flawlessly. but on my android smartphone the device info wont display after the deviceready event here is my code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, false);

function ready (){
            var deviceinfo = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
                            $('#trackinginfo').html(deviceinfo);
                                }
```

i have set the proper permission on the androidmanifest.xml

am i missing something?

thank you